# Encoding ISO-8859-1 encoded xml file correctly ios iPhone

Tags: ios, character-encoding

I have xml file with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><xml>
```

tag.
I have different languages text. i.e. Spanish, English, German, Italian etc. 
now when i try to put text into NSString with

```
NSString *contentsOfURL = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"http://link"]] encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding error:&error];
```

and parse that with CXMLDocument parser then it shows illigal characters for example

```
S√≥lo , as√≠ se dar√° cuenta etc. for Spanish language.
```

How can i sort out this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Replace your use of `NSASCIIStringEncoding` with `NSISOLatin1StringEncoding`.

ISO-8859-1 is ISO Latin 1.

Comment: Tried that. But with no luck. Thanks for reply btw